# OAuth 2 Authorization Code Grant implementation

Tags: php, vue.js, authentication, oauth-2.0, authorization

I have the following setup:

Resource Server: It is a basic RESTful API written in PHP (Slim, Doctrine)

Auth Server: My own implementation of an OAuth 2 server in PHP (Slim, Doctrine)

Public Client: A SPA written in VueJS publicly available on the web.

Further I want to authorize more clients either using the Authorization Code or the Client Credentials  grant type.

I've read most of the [official OAuth 2 Framework](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749) specification as well as several other "simple guides" and libraries implementing it.
I think I understood the theory of how the flow of the Authorization Code grant type works but have a lot of issues with all the redirects when trying to implement it.
I know have a working solution but it feels very hacky and I am certain that there has to be a simpler and better solution. Further, since I am no security expert I am concerned
that my solution is vulnerable to attacks.

Thus my question is: What would a simple and secure implementation of the OAuth 2 Authorization Code grant type look like without relying on to many 3rd party libraries.

Here I am providing an image of how I understood the flow and I am going to describe and provide code snippets of my solution.

[image]

- (Step 1 to Step 4) The user clicks the login button on the website. The Vuex action `loginOAuth` is triggered which is asking the Auth Server for a login form and displays this in a new window.

*Vuex Action `loginOAuth`*

```js
loginOAuth({commit}){
    let oauth_axios = axios.create({
      baseURL: '/php-own-oauth-server/API/public/api/v1/',
      timeout: 1000
    });
    oauth_axios({
      url: 'auth-form',
      method: 'GET'
    })
    .then(resp => {
      console.log(resp);

      let login_window = window.open('', 'My Name', 'left=0,top=0,width=800,height=500,toolbar=0,scrollbars=0,status=0');
      login_window.document.write(resp.data);
      login_window.document.close();
    })
    .catch(err => {
      commit('set_error_message', err);
    });
  },
```

- (Step 5 to Step 7) The user enters their user credentials and clicks submit on the form, which sends a POST call to the Auth Server. If the credentials are correct the server respone with
  the a code, which in my case is a short lived JWT. The response is given to the main window via `window.opener.postMessage(xhr.responseText, '*');` which to me feels very hacky. I haven't found
  a better way of doing the "redirect with code to app" step. To sign the JWT which represents the code of the grant type I am using a simple string secret since it only has to be validated on the
  same Auth Server.

*HTML Login Form, returned by OAuth Server `.../auth-form`*

```html
<head>
<script>
  window.onload = function() {
    var form = document.querySelector("form");
    form.onsubmit = submitted.bind(form);
  }

  function submitted(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open("POST", "https://localhost/php-own-oauth-server/API/public/api/v1/auth-form-validate-user-credentials");
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function(event) {
      if (xhr.readyState == XMLHttpRequest.DONE) {
        if (xhr.status == 200) {
          window.opener.postMessage(xhr.responseText, '*');
          window.close();
        }
      }
    };
    var formData = new FormData(document.getElementById("myForm"));
    xhr.send(formData);
  }
</script>
</head>
<form id="myForm">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="email">Email address</label>
    <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" name="email" aria-describedby="emailHelp">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="password">Password</label>
    <input type="password" class="form-control" name="password" id="password">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group form-check">
    <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" id="exampleCheck1">
    <label class="form-check-label" for="exampleCheck1">Remember me</label>
  </div>
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Submit">Login</button>
  <button class="btn btn-link">Password forgotten</button>
</form>
```

In the VueJS app I have the following event listener registered to receive the message sent by the login form.
It is taking the response from the Auth Server, which is mainly the code in form of a JWT token and
puts it back into the Vuex context via dispatching an action.

*JavaScript event listener to get respone from login form*

```js
window.addEventListener("message", receiveMessage, false);
function receiveMessage(event) {
  if (event.data) {
    try {
      store.dispatch('Auth/requestAccessToken', JSON.parse(event.data));
    } catch (e) {

    }
  }
}
```

- (Step 8 to Step 9) The code is used together with the client_id and client_secret (yes I know a client_secret does not make a lot of sense for a public SPA client) to request an access token from the Auth Server.

*Vuex Action `requestAccessToken`*

```js
requestAccessToken({commit}, payload){
    let oauth_axios = axios.create({
      baseURL: '/php-own-oauth-server/API/public/api/v1/',
      timeout: 1000
    });
    oauth_axios({
      url: 'request-access-token',
      method: 'POST',
      data: {
        client_id: 'frontend_app',
        client_secret: 'test123!',
        code: payload.data.code
      }
    })
    .then(resp => {
      console.log(resp);
      // resp.data.data.access_token
    })
    .catch(err => {
      commit('set_error_message', err);
    });
  }
```

From this point on the flow is straight forwad. I simply add the access token as a header to each request to the Resource Server which can validate it.
This validation is utilizes a private and public rsa key pair. The Auth Server is using the private key to sign the JWT and the Resource Server uses the public key to validate the signature.

To me this solution does not feel right. Are there better/more general solutions to implement the OAuth 2 Authorization Code grant type? I am also sceptical if my solution could be utilized by non web application clients.

Thanks for reading and helping me out.
Cheers,

Raphael Hippe

Answer (score 0):

A good goal that an OAuth architecture should meet is to externalise security, via the following steps:

- Use a Cloud Authorization Server from AWS / Google / Microsoft, which may be completely free for moderate usage
- Use an Standards based library in the SPA, to do the security heavy lifting and avoid vulnerabilities
- Focus your efforts on great UIs and APIs and get new security features for free whenever the above items are upgraded

[My blog has some visual tutorials](https://authguidance.com/2017/09/24/basicspa-overview/) to demonstrate standard solutions:

- How to integrate the most widely used library, [oidc-client](https://github.com/IdentityModel/oidc-client-js/) into your SPA, and implement the recommended Authorization Code Flow (PKCE)
- How to integrate with various Authorization Server endpoints, and an illustration of the HTTPS message payloads

Authentication related code is linked below, and, if implemented well, you won't have to write too much of it:

- [Initial SPA sample](https://github.com/gary-archer/oauth.websample1/blob/master/spa/src/plumbing/oauth/authenticator.ts)
- [Second SPA sample](https://github.com/gary-archer/oauth.websample2/blob/master/spa/src/plumbing/oauth/authenticator.ts)